# Python read file in to buffer and process results in chunks when buffer is full

Tags: python

I need to read binary file in specific chunks, but in some cases that file gets new data while being read. 
So I am thinking that solution is to read file in to buffer until buffer gets full and then process the data in the buffer and begin filling it with new data.
In this case I am reading 160 bytes.

My test code looks like this

```
with open('test.raw',"rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(160)
    while byte != b"":
        byte = f.read(160)
```

Comment: I believe the question is how to process the file 160 bytes at a time, without reading it all into memory at once.

Comment: I can see how question is not clearly formed. Sorry about that. Yes I need help with how to read only in chunks and fill the buffer while more data is coming in

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Pythonic way is to write a generator function. Since this generator handles a file resource which needs to be closed afterwards, we should wrap it in a [contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager), and consume the chunks within a `with` block.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def file_chunks(filename, chunk_size):
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    try:
        def gen():
            b = f.read(chunk_size)
            while b:
                yield b
                b = f.read(chunk_size)
        yield gen()
    finally:
        f.close()
```

Usage:

```py
with file_chunks('test.raw', 160) as chunks:
    for chunk in chunks:
        # process the chunk
        print(chunk)
```